# Moving Image Within Nested Div

Tags: html, css

I have been looking this this for about a half hour, and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong...

I have nested divs, like this:

```
<div id="header">
   <div id="header_left"><img src="~/images/image1.png"></div>
   <div id="header_right"><img src="~/images/image2.png"></div>      
</div><!--End Header-->
```

Basically, my nested divs split the screen horizontally into two equal parts, left and right.

Image1 is a logo and takes up most of header_left

Image2 is a small image, and I am trying to get it to move to the bottom right corner of header_right.

Here is my CSS:

```
#header{
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px; 
padding-left: 15px;
margin-left: 0px;
background-color: #000;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

#header_left{
float: left;
width: 50%;
}

#header_right{
float: right;
height: 100%;
width: 50%;  
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

As it stands right now, image2 is in the top left hard corner of header_right, and I cannot get it to move anywhere.

Any help appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good starting point would be to select not just the div container, but also the images as follows:

```
#header_left img{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

#header_right{
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;  
}

#header_right img{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That should do it. You must position the img using a separate rule, i.e. `#header_right > img`

```css
#header {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#header_left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
#header_right {
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
#header_right > img {

  float: right; 
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="header_left">
    <img src="~/images/image1.png">
  </div>
  <div id="header_right">
    <img src="~/images/image2.png">
    <img src="~/images/image3.png">
  </div>
</div>
<!--End Header-->
```

Comment: The only other issue I am having is how do I put one or more graphics to the left of image2??

Comment: Look at the edited example above, but keep in mind that your right header is now not 50% width anymore. If you want to keep that you might need an additional layer.